# TypeError:expected dynamic type 'string' but had type 'object' React native

Tags: react-native

I have to upload an image to cloudinary with react-native. I have used this code:

```
uploadImage(source) {
let timestamp = (Date.now() / 1000 | 0).toString();
let api_key = '***********'
let api_secret = '**************'
let cloud = '*****'
let hash_string = 'timestamp=' + timestamp + api_secret
let signature = CryptoJS.SHA1(hash_string).toString();
let upload_url = 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/' + cloud + '/image/upload'

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', upload_url);
xhr.onload = () => {
  console.log(xhr);
};
let formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('file', {uri: source, type: 'image/png', name: 'upload.png'});
formdata.append('timestamp', timestamp);
formdata.append('api_key', api_key);
formdata.append('signature', signature);
xhr.send(formdata);};
```

But I get this error:

> TypeError:expected dynamic type 'string' but had type 'object'

[image]

Comment: Try `formdata.append('file', JSON.stringify({uri: source, type: 'image/png', name: 'upload.png'}));`

Comment: yup now its working but its not uploading in the cloud..!

Comment: What response code are you getting?

Comment: "error":{"message":"Unsupported source URL: {\\"uri\\":{\\"uri\\":\\"file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/image-0eb186ab-5d04-4037-affd-dfb49b92c7ec.jpg\\"},\\"type\\":\\"image/png\\",\\"name\\":\\"upload.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you got "source" from "react-native-image-picker",
try to change

```
formdata.append('file', {uri: source, type: 'image/png', name: 'upload.png'});
```

into

```
 formdata.append('file', {uri: source.uri, type: 'image/png', name: 'upload.png'});
```

in android.
I fixed my problem in this way.